# Environment.TickCount in Python

Tags: c#, python, datetime

I've looked all over for a solution to this problem but is there any possible way with Python to the C# Environment.TickCount in Python?

I'm using the uptime library to try to do it but it doesn't seem to be very close to the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Python Uptime library](https://pythonhosted.org/uptime/) offers a cross-platform solution:

> This module provides a function—uptime.uptime()—that tells you how long your system has been up. This turns out to be surprisingly non-straightforward, but not impossible on any major platform. It tries to do this without creating any child processes...

The C# `Environment.TickCount` is in milliseconds ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount(v=vs.110).aspx)) and `uptime.uptime()` is in seconds, so converting between the two should be straightforward.

Comment: I'm trying to run this on ubuntu so that wouldn't do anything for me.

Comment: :-) let's see if there is something similar for linux then

Comment: any way to convert time in seconds to ticks?

Comment: The C# `Environment.TickCount` is in milliseconds.  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount(v=vs.110).aspx) and `uptime.uptime()` is in seconds, so converting between the two should be straight forward.

Comment: Great to hear! If you feel this has answered your question/problem, if you could mark it as the accepted answer I would really appreciate it! Thanks